# Edit ST3 xDebug config file

Tags: sublime-text-3

I'm unable to edit the xDebug configuration file which I needed to map the path to the remote server.

Tools>xDebug>settings(default)

opens the file I need, but I can't edit. Also the path of this file doesn't seem to be valid.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are likely seeing is that sublime allows for two separate settings, default and user.

The default settings are stored with the package itself (a `*.sublime-package`). This is just a renamed zip file, so while it can open the file for review/reference - you can't edit it.

The user settings are saved elsewhere in your `Packages\User` folder. Sublime is pretty smart about how it uses these, it will load the defaults first and then override any options you specify in the user file.

All that said, you have two options (assuming the plugin author used sublime's api calls).

1. Manually create the `Package (user).sublime-settings` - easiest way is save the one you opened as.
2. Unzip the package into the `Packages` directory and edit the defaults (not recommended).

Comment: So I've created an `C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Xdebug Client\Xdebug.sublime-settings` and specified mapping the remote server path to `G:/web` (which is just a folder, not local server root). The remote server has xdebug installed, by the way. Should I now start a new home server and put everything to its htdocs and refer to xdebug in the `httpd.conf` to make it work?

Comment: I dont know how xdebug works, your question was about editing the settings.  But no, I don't think those settings will apply, I think they need to be in the Users\ folder.